# How to reference the correct class in a parallel class hierarchy

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, architecture, state-machine

I have a base class that produces a text depending on its internal state. This is achieved by a state machine.

```
public abstract class BaseState
{
    // State functions

    public abstract string GetText();

    public abstract bool ShouldUpdateText();
}


public class ObjectBase // Context class
{
    public BaseState State;

    public string Text;

    public float Data1;

    public void UpdateText()
    {
        if(State.ShouldUpdateText())
       {
            Text = State.GetText();
       }
    }

    // State machine functions
}
```

State objects need a reference to the context class for its logic.

Derivations of the base context class have their own state object classes which need to work on that class.

So the class hierarchy of base context class is paralleled by the state class hierarchy.

```
public class DerivedObject1 : ObjectBase 
{
   public int[] Data2;
}

public class DerivedObject2 : DerivedObject1 
{
   public bool Data3;
}


/* Needs to work with an ObjectBase */
public class State1 : BaseState
{
   public override bool ShouldUpdateText()
   {
        return Data1 > 0;
   }
}

/* Needs to work with a DerivedObject1 */
public class State2 : BaseState
{
   public override bool ShouldUpdateText()
   {
        return Data2.Length > 2;
   }
}

/* Needs to work with a DerivedObject2 */
public class State3 : State2 
{
   public override bool ShouldUpdateText()
   {
        return base.ShouldUpdateText() && Data3;
   }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to provide a context reference to state classes as they all have different types although they share their highest parent.

Some options I considered

Type-casting through base class reference -- Feels like a code smell

```
class BaseState
{
    public ObjectBase Context;
}

public class State2 : BaseState
{
   public override bool ShouldUpdateText()
   {
        return (Context as DerivedObject1).Data2.Length > 2;
   }
}
```

Intermediate parent states for correct typed references

Doesn't work when there are states deriving from states, such as State2 & State3 in the initial example.

```
class StateForDerivedObject1 : BaseState
{
    public DerivedObject1 Context;
}

public class State2 : StateForDerivedObject1 
{
   public override bool ShouldUpdateText()
   {
        return Context.Data2.Length > 2;
   }
}
```

What is the best way to handle this problem?

Is there a better way to design the architecture that avoids this problem altogether?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, If I am understanding correctly...
You want a base class that can contain different data types.
That can be solved with generics 'ObjectBase'

The part I am not perfectly sure of is you want an
object that contains 2 of the derived classes.
Derived4 is one way of doing this, though there are many ways to do this
such as passing in both derived classes (states) into a new class (which I think would be better), but I gave an example in Derived4 of another way.

```
public class ObjectBase<T> // Context class
{
  //public BaseState<T> State;

  public string Text { get; set; }

  public T Data1 { get; set; }

  public void UpdateText ()
  {
    if ( ShouldUpdateText () )
    {
      Text = GetText ();
    }
  }

  public virtual string GetText () => throw new NotImplementedException ();

  public virtual bool ShouldUpdateText () => throw new NotImplementedException ();

  // State machine functions
}


/// <summary>
/// This is defined to use ObjectBase with data type float
/// </summary>
public class State1 : ObjectBase<float>
{
  public State1 ( string text, float data )
  {
    Text = text;
    Data1 = data;
  }
  public override bool ShouldUpdateText () => Data1 > 0;
}

/// <summary>
/// This is defined to use ObjectBase with data type int[]
/// </summary>
public class State2 : ObjectBase<int[]>
{
  public State2 ( string text, int[] data )
  {
    Text = text;
    Data1 = data;
  }
  public override bool ShouldUpdateText () => Data1.Length > 2;
}

/// <summary>
/// This is defined to use ObjectBase with data type bool
/// </summary>
public class State3 : ObjectBase<bool>
{
  public State3 ( string text, bool data )
  {
    Text = text;
    Data1 = data;
  }
  public override bool ShouldUpdateText () => Data1;
}

/// <summary>
/// Option 2: This would accept a derived class and work on that class
/// </summary>
public class Derived4 : ObjectBase<bool>
{
  private ObjectBase<bool> internalState { get; set; }
  public Derived4 ( string text, bool data, ObjectBase<bool> obj )
  {
    Text = text;
    Data1 = data;
    internalState = obj;
  }


  /// <summary>
  /// Calls the internal state objects methods
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public bool ShouldUpdateText () => internalState.ShouldUpdateText () && Data1;
}
```

Here is how to use the Derived4 class

```
// Test if encapsulation
State3 state = new State3 ( "t", true );

Derived4 state4 = new Derived4 ( "a", false, state );
if ( state4.ShouldUpdateText () )
{ }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but that doesnt seem to solve what I tried to ask. Perhaps I wasnt able to describe it well.  The ObjectBase class is a state machine, which will change states at runtime. Deriving the states from ObjectBase will prevent doing that. Also states wont just access the data of classes that derive from ObjectBase, they may also need to access their functions. So we really need a hard reference for them. Generics would work well for the states if we had some sort of template specialization in C#, but I dont think that can be done. Please correct me if I'm wrong.